# Rails where in fields of join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a select with joins in tree tables

```
.joins(module_table_1: [module_table_2: :module_table_2_type])
```

And I'd like to use `where` syntax of Active Record like this:

```
result = Module::Table_1
  .joins(module_table_1: [module_table_2: :module_table_2_type])
  .where(number: 6)
  .where(module_table_2_type: {cdg_type: [1012, 77]})
```

If I do this my `where` is composed with module name like this:

```
module_table_2_type.cdg_type in (1012,77)
```

that is not corret, the correct is:

```
table_2_type.cdg_type in (1012,77)
```

I know I can do this `.where('table_2_type.cdg_type in (1012,77)')`, with string only syntax but I want active record way to do this correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: The usage of where is like the following: `where(exact_name_of_the_table: { column_of_that_table: value })`. So in your case it must be `where(table_2_type: { cdg_type: [1012, 77] })`

Comment: tanks, this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not elegant ways to solve your problem. I'm sure there are better ways, but give it a try:

```
result = Module::Table_1
.joins("INNER JOIN table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id INNER JOIN table2_type on table2.id = table2_type.table2_id" )
.where(number: 6)
.where(table_2_type: {cdg_type: [1012, 77]})
```